# Taxonomy Term page visit report

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7, log-messages

Is there any module which tracks page visit count for taxonomy terms?

Several module exists for node visit report (including Core Statistics). But I have not found any for taxonomy term page visit count.

Some posts found suggest using the [Google Analytic](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module for this purpose. But my client does not want to use Google Analytic as this is intranet site. Still wants a report for category pages visit.

Comment: I think the module Statistics Counter may do what you want.  It works alongside the Statistics module.  I've only used it for Content though. It works in with Views.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it with Statistics module. Cannot find option for taxonomy terms.

Comment: Core stats logs visits to term pages in the db (nid in node_counter table), so you should be able to pull it out using Views by selecting your term/s and then adding a relationship via nid. See related discussion here...
https://www.drupal.org/node/603868#comment-4421144

Comment: Thanks. But as you have mentioned, stats log saves nid not tid. Can you please give more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, it comes with all sorts of reporting features. And all sorts of hooks if you want to use them in your own custom modules.

Here is an excerpt from its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363):

> Forena Reports is built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.
>
> It is designed to leverage existing knowledge of HTML, CSS, SQL and JavaScript to help you create rich interactive web reports.

In this specific case: if you know in which Drupal table (or combination of tables) the info is stored that you are looking for (like your *which tracks page visit count for taxonomy terms*), then it's a matter of putting together an appropriate SQL statement to retrieve those data, and then format it in a nicely looking report (and even chart if you'd want).

Curious to hear if this somehow could work in your case ...

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).